# Datatable export Excel, customize height of row based on content

Tags: javascript, datatables

I've a datatable that export in excel.
Each html cell has some newlines (using br, p or div) so my export in excel need to strip all tags to be compatible with excel format, but keep newline.
After some research and help from datatables users, I get this good result:

https://jsfiddle.net/jx9hom27/4/

Now my problem is to **set the height of each row to show all the text inside it**.
Actually i've hardcode value of 60 for height, but it must be calculated based on content of row.

My idea was to get the size of `splitData` array: count is the number of lines.
**The biggest value (for each row) must be multiplied for a costant (maybe 30) to get final result to apply to entire row.**

The problem is that splitData variable is outside the function that set the style for excel....how can I solve this?

The code to set the height for a row is:

```
    $('row:nth-child('+( firstExcelRow + rowLoop )+')', sheet).attr('ht', 60);
    $('row:nth-child('+( firstExcelRow + rowLoop )+')', sheet).attr('customHeight', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer myself. This is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jx9hom27/5/

counting `"` inside the entire string, and divide by 2. Then for each row establish the max found and use it for the height

```
      var countLines = ($('is t', this).text().match(/\"/g) || []).length / 2;
```